# can't use "AddFirst()" with Queue Object although initialized as LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I have been given homework in which i have to create a Queue Object and initialize it as a LinkedList Object after:

```
    Queue<Integer> Sample;
    
    Public RandomObject(){
    this.Sample = new LinkedList<Integer>;
    }
```

Now to finish my homework, i need to add an object to the **front** of the queue. I know that this doesn't work and that I need to use the function **AddFirst()**, thats why i i used LinkedList. When I try to do Sample.AddFirst() it doesnt work however.

I'm sure that must be wrong, but I'm supposed to do it that way, as written in the homework. I have tried other things but I cant come up with a solution. I could try to create **Sample** as a LinkedList Object directly and that would work, but I can't manipulate the code, its prewritten and i can only change certain lines.

Comment: The *compile-time* type of `Sample` is `Queue<Integer>`, so you can only call methods declared in `Queue<>` (and its superinterfaces). (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you learn about and start following Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Using the Dequeue interface (a double-ended queue) in place of Queue would work if this is allowed. e.g., `Dequeue<Integer> sample = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: @Jon Skeet can you tell my what was wrong? I can imagine I have to type variables without capital letters.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eeels I don't think it was intended to do it that way, but since there is no other solution, I will try that and put some comments there...

Comment: In terms of the naming conventions? Yes, variables are conventionally lower-camel-cased. (And `Public` should be `public`.) Oh, and you don't have `()` after `new LinkedList<Integer>` - basically, it really helps if you provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.